# How do I intercept server-side api calls by cypress

Tags: nuxt.js, cypress

I am using Nuxt.js as frontend framework and Laravel as api server, and writing some e2e testings with Cypress. I'm trying to reduce asyncData api call by using [cy.intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Syntax) but failed to sucessfully intercept the api call, my test spec looks like below:

```js
const siteUrl = Cypress.env('site_url')
const apiUrl = Cypress.env('api_url')
describe('Post Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept('GET', `${apiUrl}/post`, {
      fixture: 'post.json',
    })
  })
  it('should render posts same as mock data', () => {
    cy.visit(`/post`)
    cy.contains('some posts from mock data')
  })
})
```

and my posts/index.vue look like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $http }) {
      const post = await $http.$get(`${apiUrl}/post`)
      return { post }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I run the test, in asyncData hook Nuxt.js will still send actual request to Laravel asking for post data. I've read [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/588) but still want to ask is there any other ways to intercept api calls from server-side with Cypress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run a Nuxt app with server-side rendering, the `asyncData()` call is made on the server.

Data received is added to a "hydration" function at the foot of the page then served to the Cypress browser. So the `cy.intercept()` never catches the call.

One way to handle it is to mock the server during testing, which can be done in a task

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
let server;      // static reference to the mock server
                 // so we can close and re-assign on 2nd call

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    mockServer({ interceptUrl, fixture }) {

      const fs = require('fs')
      const http = require('http')
      const { URL } = require('url')

      if (server) server.close();       // close any previous instance

      const url = new URL(interceptUrl)
      server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        if (req.url === url.pathname) {
          const data = fs.readFileSync(`./cypress/fixtures/${fixture}`)
          res.end(data)
        } else {
          res.end()
        }
      })

      server.listen(url.port)
      console.log(`listening at port ${url.port}`)

      return null
    },
  })
}
```

**Test**

```js
const apiUrl = Cypress.env('api_url');   // e.g "http://localhost:9000"

cy.task('mockServer', { interceptUrl: `${apiUrl}/post`, fixture: 'post.json' })
cy.visit('/post')

// a different fixture
cy.task('mockServer', { interceptUrl: `${apiUrl}/post`, fixture: 'post2.json' })
cy.visit('/post')
```

**cypress.json**

```js
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
  "env": {
    "api_url": "http://localhost:9000"
  }
}
```

**Note**

- the Nuxt app must see the same `apiUrl`
- the mock server will always be hostname: localhost

---

**Another approach**

See [Control Next.js Server-Side Data During Cypress Tests](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/control-nextjs-data-during-tests/).

The idea is to intercept the page as it arrives from the server and modify it's hydration function.

You leave the production API server running for the test so that SSR fetches as normal.

```js
function interceptHydration( interceptUrl, fixture, key ) {
  cy.fixture(fixture).then(mockData => {
    cy.intercept(
      interceptUrl,
      (req) => {
        req.continue(res => {
          // look for "key" in page body, replace with fixture
          const regex = new RegExp(`${key}:\s*{([^}]*)}`)
          const mock = `${key}: ${JSON.stringify(mockData)}`
          res.body = res.body.replace(regex, mock)
        })
      }
    )
  })
}

it('changes hydration data', () => {
  interceptHydration( '/post', 'post', 'post' )
  cy.visit('/post')
  cy.get('h1').contains('post #2')   // value from fixture
})
```

Comment: It works! Now all I need is to extend it to support HTTP methods, thank you! Can I ask how you worked this out? I couldn't find it on Cypress official doc

Comment: From your description it seemed that [start-server-and-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test) was the way to go, picking the simplest server (node http) it seemed easier to wrap it in a task - the whole thing is less fuss for anyone who knows Cypress.

Comment: What is the key parameter in the interceptHydration function referencing?

Comment: @RichardMatsen, according cypress docs is not good to run a server in cypress env.  (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) like in your first example. Could this affect somehow the app?